# Is there a way to group subplots onto a single row in order to stack them vertically?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have 3 subplots I need to display like so:
[image]
I have been successful in creating 2 subplots side by side but I am struggling to find (or describe) a way to get the above structure.

I am using a `FuncAnimation` to animate the data as it is plotted.

```py
self.figure, (self.plot1, self.plot2) = plt.subplots(
            1, 2, figsize=(16, 9), width_ratios=[3, 1])
```

I need to keep the width ratios the same, does anyone have a way I can achieve this?

Comment: [`plt.subplot_mosaic`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot_mosaic.html) can do this very easily. Use a two-row mosaic, e.g. `AB` and `AC` for the rows.

Comment: `fig, axes = plt.subplot_mosaic("AB;AC", figsize=(16, 9), width_ratios=[3, 1])`